# Displaying a tree with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have tree data in mysql table. I have ID and parentID. I wish to display a tree structure with Ajax. When I click on the node, I want to sent a parameter to a page and return a data and then use the data to display the children.

```
<body>
<div id='jstree'>
</div>
<script>
  $(function () {
    // 6 create an instance when the DOM is ready
    $('#jstree').jstree({
      'core' : {
      'data' : {
       'url' : 'abc.asp?',
      'data' : function (node) {
       return { 'accno' : node.id };
     }
   }
  }
});
    // 7 bind to events triggered on the tree
    $('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
      console.log(data.selected);
    });
    // 8 interact with the tree - either way is OK
    $('button').on('click', function () {
      $('#jstree').jstree(true).select_node('child_node_1');
      $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', 'child_node_1');
      $.jstree.reference('#jstree').select_node('child_node_1');
    });
  });
 </script>
</body>
```

I really hope you guys can help me out. What I want to achieve after my research is called lazy loading. 
Say I have a sql table with the following data.

```
   Accno    Referral 
    L1A
    L1B  
    L2A1       L1A   
    L2A2       L1A
    L2A3       L1A    
    L2B1       L1B
    L2B2       L1B
    L2B3       L1B
    L3A1       L2A1
    L3A2       L2A1 
    L3B1       L2B3 
    L3B2       L2B2
   and so on
```

1. Initially I want to load L1A and L1B with + sign indicates they have children
2. When clicked on the node with children, say L1A.

   - How to pass a url with parameter of accno L1A to another page to process? How to indicate node.id is L1A(will it automatically be detected when I click on the node?)
3. Pass the url abc.asp?accno="L1A" to a html/asp page to process.
4. Find the children with accno="L1A" in SQL statement, 
   select .... with referral = 'L1A'
   flag the results for those with children and those without children.
5. Return the results.

   - **How do I return results, in HTML file?** I can format it in any strings but what is format?
6. And, how does JSTREE pick up the results and display?

Please help.

Comment: You can use jqTree or jsTree

Comment: can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your responds. I have edited my post to show my progress. Please help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jstree`. `jsTree` is `jquery` plugin, that provides interactive trees. It is absolutely free, open source and distributed under the MIT license. jsTree is easily extendable, themable and configurable, it supports HTML & JSON data sources and AJAX loading.

jsTree functions properly in either box-model (content-box or border-box), can be loaded as an AMD module, and has a built in mobile theme for responsive design, that can easily be customized. It uses jQuery's event system, so binding callbacks on various events in the tree is familiar and easy.

[Reference](https://www.jstree.com/)

[JSTree Example with Php & Mysql](https://github.com/pandeyz/JStree-with-data-from-mysql-database)

Comment: Hi I have edited to show what I have done, please help. thank you very much.